# webshere application server 9.0(WAS 9.0)

Tags: websphere-9

I have a project about custom tag JSP

when i build war file and deploy on tomcat 8.0 then run and not error.

but i deploy on WAS 9.0 the error( but deploy on WAS 8.5 run is not error):

Error message :
JSPG0049E: /index.jsp failed to compile:

JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line 3 of file /index.jsp

JSPG0093E: Servlet error from file: /index.jsp

D: \ WebServer \ WebSphere \ AppServer \ profiles \ AppSrv01 \ temp \ mutb04kNode01 \ server1 \ sample1_war \ sample1.war \ _ibmjsp \ _index.java: 120: The method inject (T) is ambiguous for the type AnnotationHelper

please help me about error. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue with your Java code at line 120.

Either you can share your code or you can check [this reference](https://www.journaldev.com/9107/the-method-is-ambiguous-for-the-type-java-ambiguous-method-call-null-error).